# Model evaluation from a checkpoint with Multi GPU

Tags: tensorflow, multi-gpu

I know how to train a network on a single GPU -> save a checkpoint -> later on load this checkpoint -> run benchmarks.

I can't figure how to do it when I train using multiple GPUs and using the new Data API.

Here is the 'normal' training code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf


images_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, image_size, 
image_size, 1), name='input')
labels_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(None))

embeddings = build_graph(images_placeholder)
loss = add_loss(embeddings, labels_placeholder)

embeddings = tf.identity(embeddings, 'embeddings')
```

Later on, when I want to benchmark:

```py
with tf.Graph().as_default():

with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)) as sess:

    load_graph_def(model_path)  # for example: d:\model.ckpt-0

    images_placeholder = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("input:0")
    embeddings = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("embeddings:0")

    images = benchmark_utils.load_data(paths_batch, image_size)
    feed_dict = {images_placeholder: images}
    predictions = sess.run(embeddings, feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

So now I want to train with multiple GPUs like so:

```py
with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.device('/cpu:0'):

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((images_list, labels_list))
dataset = dataset.map(load_images)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=100)
dataset = dataset.batch(128)
dataset = dataset.repeat()

opt = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(0.01, momentum=0.9, use_nesterov=True)

tower_grads = []
with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope()):
    for i in range(num_gpus):
        with tf.device('/gpu:%d' % i):
            with tf.name_scope('%s_%d' % (TOWER_NAME, i)) as scope:
                image_batch, label_batch = dataset.iterator.get_next()
                loss = tower_loss(scope, image_batch, label_batch)
```

What I can't figure out is how can I get the 'input' and 'embeddings' tensor when I want to benchmark the checkpoint.

**How do I define for example the tensor called 'input' that should receive the images that should be evaluated ?**

I'm guessing that somewhere in the multi-gpu code, I should define this `images_placeholder` like I defined in the single-gpu training.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Hi ! You should look at the [cifar-10 example](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py), I think you'll get some hindsight at how to achieve multi-gpu training.

Comment: Thanks for the edits :) I'm training with multiple GPUs according to the cifar-10 example. As far as I can tell, it doesn't include a solution for the problem that I'm facing.